# Why are the spaces (%20) in my URL interpreted as '_' signs?

Tags: http, internet-explorer-8, cgi

I am using IE version 8 in my web application.
I am sending string which consist of blank space character which i have encoded as "%20". When I send this string to a specific URL,it interprets "%20" as underscore sign instead of Blank space. can anybody tell me what might have gone wrong?

Comment: How do you send it? In the URL? As a POST variable?

Comment: Is this a IE8 only issue or does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: its only IE8 issue,works fine in all other browsers

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson:: yes its been sent as a post variable

Comment: Still can't reproduce, works for me. Could you make a minimal example of how you're encoding and sending the string? Is it server generated as a hidden field or generated by ajax or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson the string is encoded in form  "stFileName=stFamilyName+"%20Comprehensive%20Report%20"+stdate[1]+stdate[2]+stdate[0]+".pdf"; "

Comment: Maybe the page that you are posting to is wrongly converting to underscore by error or design.

Answer (score 0):

there cant be just a space in computer code, which is why it has an underscore (*) instead of a blank spaces.  The unicode symbol of an underscore or a "*" is represented by "%20"

Comment: Perhaps you could also post some links to unicode/html/URL-encoding sites to help clarify your answer?